# Is there a Powershell cmdlet for querying the Azure Subscriptions' Credit Status?

Tags: powershell, azure, subscriptions

How can one get their Azure subscriptions' credit status thru Powershell ?

[image]

The Azure module has no cmdlets that can query the credit status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is you can't. Azure PowerShell is a wrapper over Azure REST API and right now the billing/usage is not exposed via REST API. Some tool providers rely on screen scraping to get this data programmatically.

Comment: There're no CLI tools that I'm aware of. Quest Software used to have a tool (not sure if they still do) which did that.